# My dynamic API path for Axios does not appear to be formed correctly

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to pass in an API path and other data into my React component as you can examine below.

I want to build the api path dynamically because various other parts of the web app will hit this React component with different API paths.

When I run it, nothing happens.  I also put a breakpoint on the API controller that is supposed to be hit, but it never is. There are also no errors in the browser console.

When I hard code the api path, it works fine.

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

What is the proper way to do this?

thanks!

```
 const App = ({ objectId, objectType, test, myTestApiUrl }) => {
   
   const updateValue = (value) => {
        const request = axios.put(`{myTestApiUrl}${objectId}/{objectType}`, JSON.stringify(value), {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }

        }).catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            }
        });
    }
    
    
    const updateYourData = (content) => {
        const request = updateValue(content);
        test.trigger('change', testModel, {});
    }
    
    // test
    updateYourData("123 ABC");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function `updateValue` needs to return its promise to be consumed by `updateYourData`. also you may mark `updateYourData` as async in order to retrieve your promise value to `request` variable:

```
const App = ({ objectId, objectType, test, myTestApiUrl }) => {
  
  const updateValue = (value) => {
      return axios.get(`{myTestApiUrl}${objectId}/{objectType}`, JSON.stringify(value), {
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }

      }).catch(function (error) {
          if (error.response) {
              console.log(error.response.data);
              console.log(error.response.status);
              console.log(error.response.headers);
          }
      });
  }
  
  
  const updateYourData = async (content) => {
      const request = await updateValue(content);
      test.trigger('change', testModel, {});
  }
  
  // test
  updateYourData("123 ABC");
}
```